# Print the content of a VBO

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I'm modifying bits of a OpenGL_accelerate.vbo.VBO object at different moments, and I'd like to print the actual whole content this object (for debug purpose).

A simple `print(my_vbo)` doesn't work (it prints `<OpenGL_accelerate.vbo.VBO object at 0x0000019FA8370430>`)

Is there a simple way to get it with PyOpenGL (or must I maintain a numpy copy of the data) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array of `GLfloat` and read the buffer back from the GPU into that array with [`glGetBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetBufferSubData.html). Finally, you can print the array as a list

```py
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)

no_of_floats = 12 # read 12 floats
float_array = (GLfloat * no_of_floats)()
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, no_of_floats * sizeof(GLfloat), float_array)
print(list(float_array))
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked, and I finally fixed my code! Thanks a lot!